# PI Zero gadget with g_ether on Ubuntu host creates new wired connection every boot

Tags: networking, ethernet, ubuntu, gadget

I have a Raspberry PI Zero running Raspbian Stretch 2017-09-07 configured in otg mode with the g_ether module loaded.

When I set a static IP in the interfaces files, connecting on Windows is successful. However, Ubuntu will NOT connect successfully. When I remove the static IP reference from the interfaces file, I can successfully connect to the PI via Ubuntu (after the usual connection config), but if the PI is reconnected, Ubuntu will generate a new network connection with the default settings.

Is there something I'm missing in configuring the PI, so I don't have to edit a new wired connection every time I connect the PI to an Ubuntu host?

Comment: And what MAC address do you get between the reconnect the Raspberry PI?

Comment: @MatsK Ubuntu reports 1a:0a:b1:c3:7f:6a, and the PI reports 32:be:b9:16:0a:44. Both report different IP addresses and device types for the same connection. The PI reports the connection as USB0 link/ether, and Ubuntu reports unknown link/ether. After a reconnect, both devices report again different mac and ip addresses.